# Passing multiple parameters in a hyperlink in yii2 with clean urls, Html::a() doesnt generate clean url

Tags: yii2, clean-urls, yii-url-manager

I am trying to generate a hyper link by the method mentioned in 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#hyperlinks like this

```
 Html::a('<b>Register</b>', 
    ['story/create', array('id' =>39,'usr'=>'11')], 
    ['class' => 'profile-link'])
```

I want to get url like  `story/create/id/39/usr/11`

But it is generating as

```
story/create?1%5Bid%5D=39&1%5Busr%5D=1
```

I have enabled the clean url functionality of yii2 like

```
  'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
        ], also.
```

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With generate `url` use like that (see more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html):

```
Html::a('<b>Register</b>', 
        ['story/create', 'id' =>39,'usr'=>'11'], 
        ['class' => 'profile-link'])
```

In urlManager input new rule:

```
rules' => array(
  ....
  'story/create/<id:\d+>/<usr:\d+>' => 'story/create',

        ),
```

Output url will be like that:

```
story/create/39/11
```

And in controller:

```
public function actionCreate($id, $usr)
```

And Yii2 provide this parameter.

Comment: it is still generating like story/create?1%5Bid%5D=39&1%5Busr%5D=1

Comment: In `Html` in set `['story/create', 'id' =>39,'usr'=>'11'], `?

Comment: It is now creating like reg/create/39?usr=1 , I need ? to be removed

Comment: I tried and it is work fine. look - https://yadi.sk/i/neiWnrkufW43J and https://yadi.sk/i/pSvwF5GSfW49Z and my `.htaccess` https://yadi.sk/i/4jsoxNwffW4D9

Comment: I dont know it is like create/39?usr=1 , may be some thing related to  generation of hyperlink by Html::a()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73740/discussion-between-vitalik-74-and-user7282).

Comment: I got it working , this should be in the first line of rules, it it is at the end it generates '?'You  may verify  it or find a better solution

Comment: After you send it you can get the data with: print_r(Yii::$app->request->get()['id']; and print_r(Yii::$app->request->get()['usr'] );

Answer (score 1):

create Url Dynamically

```
Html::a('<b>Register</b>', 
    ['story/create', 'id' =>39,'usr'=>'11'], 
    ['class' => 'profile-link'])
```

In urlManager config rules :

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
             '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',            
             '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<usr:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>', 
        ],
    ],
```

Output url will be like that:

```
story/create/39/11
```

Answer (score 0):

Another useful method :

Write in urlManager rules in your

```
'rules'=>array('/controller/action/<limit>/<offset>'=>'/controller/action/'),
```

Can be accessed in url controller/action/100/20